# How to solve issue of multiple links as output while scraping site using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

am new to python and learning web scraping. Am trying to scrape title and link (not title link) from a site like this:

```
            Title 1
            Link 1

            Title 2 
            Link 2

            Title 3
            Link 3
```

but the issue is am not able to do in this manner, I tried to do this with nesting for loop(link) inside for loop(title) but it prints the Title as above but also prints links of all the title instead of one, like this.

```
            Title 1
            Link 1
            Link 2
            Link 3


            Title 2
            Link 1
            Link 2
            Link 3


            Title 3
            Link 1
            Link 2
            Link 3
```

I have everything to solve this issue for no luck! can anyone please help.

Can i add sets to solve this issue? since sets avoid duplicates am thinking it might help.

my code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    for title in soup.findAll("html_element", {"attribute": "value "}):      #loop for title
        tit = title.string
        print("\n",tit)
        for link in soup.findAll("html_element", {"attribute": "value "}):   #loop for links
            href = link.get("href")
            print(href)
           #break


scrape("http://www.website.com/")
```

Comment: Could you add a small example of the html ? maybe you could refer to a `title` directly in the first loop to get the link, without looping twice

Comment: html elements, attribute and values for both title and links are different that's why its not possible to do in one loop

Comment: you may be right, but since you are using the same selector to list the nodes, they might be less different than you think. A small sample could help here

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to make two python lists containing these names. 
In one list you add each 'title' and the other you add the 'links'. These lists will be part of the nested for loops. In the end, you will have to use the %s operator to change the attributes corresponding to the html snippet.